# Como exibir/esconder texto usando uma imagem como botão?

Tags: html

Oi, eu estou montando um pequeno site onde eu queria usar varias imagens como botão que ao clicar cada um exibisse um texto diferente, como eu posso fazer isso?

Eu testei esse aqui mas ele não fecha o primeiro texto ao abrir o segundo, fica tudo misturado no mesmo espaço.

```html
<div class="divspoiler">
<input type="image" src="IMAGEM AQUI" onclick="if (this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display != '') { this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display = ''; this.value = 'Ocultar'; } else { this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display = 'none'; this.value = 'Mostrar'; }" />
</div><div><div class="spoiler" style="display: none;">TEXTOOOOOO
</div></div>
```

Comment: " fecha o primeiro texto ao abrir o segundo" onde está o segundo texto ? Só vejo um na pergunta

Comment: Use jquery para facilitar, vocë pode aprender mais no w3schools.
pesquise sobre seletores [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) e sobre eventos [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp)

Comment: Opa eu hospedei o site pra vocês verem como esta http://digimonworld1.000webhostapp.com/ os botoes que fiz ate agora são os dois primeiros bichinhos da coluna rosa, eu queria que o texto sumisse ao clicar em qualquer outro lugar da pagina, sem ter que clicar no bichinho de novo.

Comment: Sugiro que tente reproduzir o mesmo problema aqui reduzindo ao minimo necessário, porque o que tem na pergunta parece-me um pouco diferente do que está no seu site

Answer (score 3):

Um Exemplo que pode ajudar

```js
//array de objetos que armazena o link das imagens e o texto de cada imagem,
        //pode ser um arquivo JSON externo
        var imgTexto = [
          {"img":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ae/d7/bc/aed7bcbe347a262f89cc3867cdce54c2--cutest-kittens-ever-cute-baby-animals.jpg",
          "txt":"Texto da Imagem 1"},
          {"img":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2e/51/4d/2e514d03b0414f8b7c5adefa5cbccba4--wink-wink-adorable-animals.jpg",
          "txt":"Texto da Imagem 2"}
        ];

        //variavel img armazena as strings das tags <img /> ja prontas para inserir no HTML
        // geradas pelo for que vem a seguir
        var img = "";

        //for percorre o array de objetos e cria tags<img /> formatadas para inserir no HTML
        for(var key in imgTexto) {
          img += "<img src='"+imgTexto[key].img+"' onclick='mostraTexto("+key+")' />";
        }

        //insere tags <img /> com todas as imagems do array na div com id="imgs"
        document.getElementById("imgs").innerHTML = img;

        //função que mostra o texto referte a imagem que possui a msm key
        function mostraTexto(key) {

          document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = imgTexto[key].txt;
        }
```

```css
img {
        border: 10px solid white;
        outline: 1px solid black;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
      }
```

```html
<div id="imgs"></div>
<div id="texto"></div>
```

Tentei deixar bem comentado para ajudar a compreensão. Clique em executar para ver funcionando. pelo que entendi é isso que está tentando fazer.